# Using Regex.match on char

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How do I use for example this line:

```
Regex.Matches(str,@"[a-zA-Z]");
```

that instead of the str I will have a char?

Comment: You could just try `"" + chr` or `chr.ToString()` turning it into a string...

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here.  Are you trying to convert a 1 character `string` into a `char`?  And validate that it is a letter?

Comment: It sounds to me like you just need `Char.IsLetter` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `ToString` on character and then use that like:

```
char ch = 'c';
Regex.Matches(ch.ToString(),@"[a-zA-Z]");
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to test if a character is a letter. You do not need a regular expression to do that. Instead you can use the following:

```
var isLetter = Char.IsLetter(ch);
```

However, this will return true for all UNICODE letters, not only A-Z, e.g. also accented letters like É or other letters like Æ and 你.

If you want to only test for A-Z (upper and lower case) you can use this simple test:

```
var upperCaseCh = Char.ToUpperInvariant(ch);
var isLetter = 'A' <= upperCaseCh && upperCaseCh <= 'Z';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use the static functions of the char class or use the comparison operators, i.e.

```
var test = 'a' <= c && c <= 'z';
```

The static methods can give you the character class, e.g. letter, digit or whitespace.

Comment: You can probably make this a bit easier to read by using `'a' <= c && c <= 'z'` I think.